# Mention marking duty for a course in an early academic career CV

Tags: postdocs, cv, grading

I am first year post-doctoral fellow. I have been asked to carry out some marking duties by my PhD supervisor from another university which I am not currently affiliated with, but where I got my PhD from.

Can I mention this marking duty under my teaching experience on my academic CV?

Comment: Why are you doing grading for another university?

Comment: I was asked by my PhD supervisor if I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mention it, but there is no benefit to doing so.  Your marking and grading experience is not important to hiring decisions.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your only teaching experience, you might want to mention it. If you are doing it in a non-native language that you have no other documentation of using, you might want mention it.

Otherwise, it might make a very weak case that you have connections to that university in particular, but presumably that is clear, since it is your PhD institute.